# Is there any PCL-compatible BDD framework that can be used with Xamarin (and preferably xUnit.Net)

Tags: testing, mobile, xamarin, bdd, xunit.net

These days, I'm looking into Xamarin and Mobile Programming with .NET. More precisely, I'm currently trying to make my way through the related testing story.

I'm well used to do TDD and also to write a lot of BDD-style tests in C#/.NET with various frameworks (both for unit testing and for BDD). I find BDD tests especially useful when it comes to testing complex business logic that spans multiple components (e.g. database stuff).

I quickly found out that the best choice for unit testing against shared code that resides in a PCL is [xUnit.Net](http://xunit.github.io/). Now I'm in search for a BDD framework that complements this ensemble.

Does anybody know how this can be done, or know of any other way to do BDD-style testing in a PCL environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a very nice and detailed article on how to write cross-platform BDD tests on the Xamarin Platform:

**[BDD Tests with Xamarin.UITest and SpecFlow](http://arteksoftware.com/bdd-tests-with-xamarin-uitest-and-specflow/)**